# How to create OleVariant compatible class in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Delphi 2006. XML Data Binding.
Generate this class:

```
type
  IXMLItem = interface(IXMLNode)  
    ['{10B9A877-A975-4FC7-B9EF-448197FA1B90}']  
    { Property Accessors }
    function Get_PartNum: TPartNum_Sku;
    procedure Set_PartNum(Value: TPartNum_Sku);
    { Methods & Properties }
    property PartNum: TPartNum_Sku read Get_PartNum write Set_PartNum;
  end;

  { TXMLItem }

  TXMLItem = class(TXMLNode, IXMLItem)
  protected
    { IXMLItem }
    function Get_PartNum: TPartNum_Sku;
    procedure Set_PartNum(Value: TPartNum_Sku);
  end;
...
function TXMLItem.Get_PartNum: TPartNum_Sku;
begin
  Result := AttributeNodes['partNum'].NodeValue;
end;

procedure TXMLItem.Set_PartNum(Value: TPartNum_Sku);
begin
  SetAttribute('partNum', Value);
end;
```

How to create OleVariant compatible class TPartNum_Sku?
So what would the code:

```
Result := AttributeNodes['partNum'].NodeValue;
```

translated without error

```
[Pascal Error] ipo1.pas(394): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TPartNum_Sku' and 'OleVariant'
```

Comment: Is TPartNum_Sku an interface or an enum (integer + consts) or a class?

Comment: Assume that this class.
I just also is the question: how to create a type that would be compatible with OleVariant?
If this class is from whom he must inherit or implement any interfaces?

Answer (score 1):

You're reading the value of an XML attribute, and you're trying to assign it to something of type `TPartNum_Sku`. The compile-time type of the attribute value is `OleVariant`, but since XML attributes are always strings, the run-time type of the value stored in that `OleVariant` will always be `WideString`. It will never hold a value of type `TPartNum_Sku`, so your goal of defining that class to be compatible with `OleVariant` is misguided because they don't need to be compatible. (Just because that's what the compiler says the problem is doesn't mean that's how you need to fix it. The compiler sometimes says "semicolon expected," but it rarely means you should add a semicolon right there.)

The entire point of having your `Get_PartNum` function is so that you can *convert* the string attribute value into a `TPartNum_Sku` object. If `TPartNum_Sku` is a class, you could call its constructor:

```
Result := TPartNum_Sku.Create(AttributeNodes['partNum'].NodeValue);
```

Beware, though, that when you do that, the *caller* of `Get_PartNum` is responsible for freeing that object.

If your type is an enumeration, then your conversion depends on what the attribute value is. If it's the numeric value of the enumeration, then you could use this:

```
Result := TPartNum_Sku(StrToInt(AttributeNodes['partNum'].NodeValue));
```

If it's the string name, then you could try this:

```
Result := TPartNum_Sku(GetEnumValue(TypeInfo(TPartNum_Sku),
                                    AttributeNodes['partNum'].NodeValue);
```

[`GetEnumValue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/TypInfo.GetEnumValue) is in the *TypInfo* unit. You could also try [`IdentToInt`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.IdentToInt), from the *Classes* unit.

You'll have to write inverse code for your `Set_PartNum` function, too.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Next excuse for my bad English :-)
What you have proposed is understandable.
But I have a somewhat different problem: there is a XSD file on it is generated using XML Data Binding pas-file with the classes and interfaces describing the scheme and would like to take this pas-file, changing the minimum, while having normal classes for work.

Comment: While we have simple types like integer, string, etc. everything works. But once you want something strange, you have to enter their types (that allows itself XML Data Binding) and edit the generated code.
The result is very unpleasant to work when the scheme changes.